# Dealing with React Router on Apache server

Tags: reactjs, apache, react-router

I am experiencing problems with redirecting 404 errors for URL paths generated by React on an Apache server.

**Scenario:**

Let's say I have some URL generated by React Router: www.somewebsite.com/apps

**Problem**:

How do I redirect back to www.somewebsite.com/apps if the end-user clicks on refresh?

**What I have tried:**

So far, I am able to redirect the user to www.somewebsite.com. I just need to get the path before the redirect.

Comment: Are you server server rendering?

Comment: No. There is no rendering done from the server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set an Apache rewrite rule to rewrite all requests to your React app (index.html).

Put this in your vhost config or a .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Now, when a user presses refresh (or visits directly) on any route like `/apps`, your React app will be loaded and the router will display the relevant route.

Note: the `RewriteCond` excludes static files from being rewritten which is necessary.

Comment: Where would you put that .htaccess file? In the /var/www/html/*subdirectory* folder?

Comment: For anyone coming here, this solved my routing problem. Just to answer that, ```.htaccess``` file should be created in the directory you want its directives to apply to. This thread was usefull too: https://serverfault.com/questions/161473/htaccess-location

Answer (score 0):

In my react case this error happened only when I navigate to links with more than one slash:
E.g.
[www.abc.com/support](http://www.abc.com/support) works with Apache rewrite rule but [www.abc.com/support/email@gmail.com](http://www.abc.com/support/email@gmail.com) fails

My solution was to open index.html and make all links point back to main domain.
Replace `"./"`
with `"/"`

Comment: To fix this error, simply specify the homepage in your package.json, for example:

  "homepage": "http://mywebsite.com"

Answer (score 0):

Since Apache 2.2.16, you can set up a [`FallbackResource`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource) under the `<Directory>` or `<VirtualHost>` configuration.

```
FallbackResource /index.html
```

This will serve `index.html` for all URLs that do not map to a file, which allows React Router to handle the URL.