# Plesk shows 404 page not found Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, frontend, plesk, web-frontend

I am trying to upload my application to Plesk and it is working fine except when i try to render non .HTML page component for example it through error 404 page not found I understand this related to the server but I don`t know how to fix it.
I have uploaded the same application on Vercel and it is working fine on all pages and components.

```
<Route exact path="/" render={() => {window.location.href="Home.html"}} />
<Route path="/quiz" component={App} />
<Route path="/questions" render={() => {window.location.href="questions.html"}} />
<Route path="/profile" render={() => {window.location.href="profile.html"}} />
<Route path="/about" render={() => {window.location.href="about.html"}} />
```

As u can see most of my routes are to .HTML pages and they are all working when i visit domain/quiz i get 404 page not found.

I would appreciate if there is a fix for that.

And i have already tried to create the .htaccess as recommended in many previous solutions but it did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The solution suggested by this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60342849/7345217 worked

Create a .htaccess file in the Public folder of your React App.

Put these lines in the file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options -MultiViews
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Save and (npm react or yarn build) and it should work

Comment: still getting same error

Answer (score 0):

In my case i create a .htaccess file in the Public folder of your React App.
Put these lines in the file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

and create a _redirects file in the Public folder of your React App.

Put this lines in the file

```
/*    /index.html   200
```

also create web.config in plesk hosting folder where build is uploaded and wrote

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
        <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <error statusCode="404" path="/" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

and it works..!